# Marshal void* to array<byte>^

Tags: c++-cli, marshalling, managed-c++

I am looking to write a `void*` buffer to a `MemoryStream` in a C++/CLI. As I don't think this is possible directly, alternatively I would like to convert this buffer to an `array<byte>^` in order to be able to call `Stream.Write()`. I've looked at `Marshal` but then I am having trouble coverting `void*` to `System::IntPtr`. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am having trouble coverting void* to System::IntPtr. Any help is appreciated.

You can use the [IntPtr constructor which takes a `void*`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z82h6h45.aspx):

```
void* voidPointer = GetTheVoidPointer();
System::IntPtr intPointer(voidPointer);
```

Comment: Oh, it never occurred to me it could be this simple. Thanks a lot! And it was quick too!